# Propel Generator missing when installed using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, propel

I am using propel via composer. But I am not able to use propel-gen command as mentioned [here](http://propelorm.org/Propel/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html)

```
> propel-gen datadump
```

Although I was able to use the reverse command via propel.bat, but when I use datadump command I get this:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/propel.bat datadump
[InvalidArgumentException]
Command "datadump" is not defined.
```

This is how my composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*",
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["controllers/"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Propel-gen does not exist/apply anymore in Propel 2.0. U need to use the command `propel model:build`. Please refer to the new [build proces](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html) for propel 2.0 as your looking at the 1.X documentation. The new layout is blue, the old one is more yellow :) thats how u can know fast

Comment: I really like the idea of Dumping Data to XML as mentioned here: http://propelorm.org/Propel/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html#dumping-data-to-xml

Is it possible to achieve that in 2.x version?

Answer (score 0):

According to you composer.json you've installed Propel v2.x

For Propel v2.x onwards the command is `Propel`.

Also the link you included is for 1.x not 2.x